# Trying to declare variable within useEffect:

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm really not sure what I am doing wrong

Please help out...

Is there a better way to access a variable declared within the useEffect?

Thanks

So I have the following code - but I get the error:
`[TypeError: "setDevice" is read-only]`

```
const [device, setDevice] = useState( '' );
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const device_id = async () => {
      var DeviceInfo = require('react-native-device-info');
      var deviceId = DeviceInfo.getUniqueId();
      const filePath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + deviceId + "_secret.json";
      if (await RNFS.exists(filePath)){
        RNFS.readFile(filePath, 'utf8')
        .then((contents) => {
          try{
            // setDev = String(contents);
            var JSONObject = JSON.parse(contents);
            console.log(JSONObject['device_id']); 
            setDevice = JSONObject['device_id'];
          }catch(err){
            console.log("Error: ", err);
          }
          
        });
        console.log("FILE EXISTS: " + filePath);
    } else {
      function makeid() {
        var text = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
      
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
          text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
      
        return text;
      }
      var dev_id = makeid() + deviceId;
      var id = '{"device_id" : "'+dev_id+'"}';
      RNFS.writeFile(filePath, id, 'utf8')
        .then((success) => {
          console.log('FILE WRITTEN!');
          navigation.dispatch(resetReachOutPreferences)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.message);
        });
      } 
    }
    device_id();
  }, []);
  console.log("ID: " + device);
```

I've tried useState(null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [React documentation on the State hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html):

> **What does useState return?** It returns a pair of values: the current state and a function that updates it.

So in this case, `setDevice` is a function that can be used to update the value of `device` (which will be reflected on subsequent renders). Instead of assigning to it, you should call it with the new value as its argument, e.g.:

```
setDevice(contents);
```